# run a wordpress shortcode

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, shortcode

Please, do not downvote... and if you need more details please ask in comments...!!!

I have a WordPress shortcode. `"[something]"` . It loads perfectly if the page is loaded with this shortcode... but my problem starts here:-

**I want to load different shortcode on based on different actions. 
my shortcode is stored in a javascript variable and now I want to load this shortcode from that variable after the Wordpress page is completely loaded...**

for an example: the action like *clicking a button,* or *like an input box*... the shortcode is going to **differ each time...**

note: I know shortcodes work through PHP function and PHP is loaded before javascript but is there any way to complete my purpose???

here's my javascript function

```
   function showjob() { 
    var intrest=document.getElementById("intrest").value; 
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'jobsloader.php',
            data: {
                intrest: intrest,
                type: 'need'
            },
            success: function(data) 
            {
                // run recieved shortcode and display it in addcontainer
                document.getElementById("addcontainer").innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    }
```

this is an example shortcode that might return

```
 [sc_team style="horizontal" team="Karina Marie" columns="3"]
```

remember shortcode may vary on the basis of value javacript variable "interest"

Comment: yon can achieve by ajax call?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to achieve but JavaScript can easily hide and show a `<div>` or other element, so you can have your PHP/shortcode output several widgets which are `display: none`, then show the one you want visible.

Comment: yes, i am getting the shortcode from an ajax call... but how to use this shortcode after the wordpress page is completely loaded @Vel

Comment: you can append the shortcode in jquery?

Comment: the shortcode are going differ each time so it has unlimited types... that can't be used at once @ChrisG

Comment: @vel how to?? plz add an answer

Comment: can you post your code? so i can explain more

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), please describe what you actual goal is, independent of wordpress or shortcodes.

Comment: @vel see updated question

Comment: @ChrisG see updated question

Comment: ajax return shortcode or shortcode html?

Comment: whole problem is that... it return the shortcode not html... because the php page is totally cutom build i cant run the do_shortcode() there!!! @Vel

Comment: @user10280601 You don't really need a shortcode for that; just compose and echo your HTML in `jobsloader.php`, as with any standard AJAX request. If you need Wordpress specific functions, add the according `include` statement.

Comment: you can use different ajax call function and echo the shortcode in ajax function?

Comment: Why do you need to use shortcodes? Whats the benefit, whats the requirement? Just use AJAX the way it's meant in Wordpress: https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Comment: which file should be included to run shortcodes...

Comment: Took me five seconds of Googling: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/files/wp-includes/shortcodes.php/

Comment: @ChrisG already tried it... but it didnt work so i thought more files are needed to be included...

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108874/loading-shortcode-with-ajax https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53309/why-might-a-plugins-do-shortcode-not-work-in-an-ajax-request

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use Ajax for this. You can follow the below steps
1. On JS events call an Ajax request
2. Pass the shortcode name in the request parameters like **SITE_URL/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=handle_shortcode&short_code_name=name_of_shortcode**
3. In Ajax request handler on server use code **do_shortcode('short_code_name')**
4. Show the content returned by the server in the page.

In themes, function.php file add the following

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_handle_shortcode', 'handle_shortcode' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_handle_shortcode', 'handle_shortcode' );

function handle_shortcode( ) {
    $shortcode = $_REQUEST['shortcode_name'];
    echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
    exit;
}
```

Then modify your js code like below

```
function showjob() {
    var intrest=document.getElementById("intrest").value;
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: {
                action: 'handle_shortcode', //You can pass other parameters to be used in shortcode
                shortcode_name: intrest
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                // run recieved shortcode and display it in addcontainer
                document.getElementById("addcontainer").innerHTML = data;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Tried your code... but on success it is returning 0... why??? i am sending actual shortcode at the place of shortcode_name

Comment: Probably you need to add add_action( 'wp_ajax_handle_shortcode', 'handle_shortcode' );. Please check updated code.

Comment: no matter if i paste the code in function.php the admin-ajax.php is returning 0....